publisher-github- Electron forge project doesn´t recognize environment variable GITHUB-TOKEN
I have already defina my .env file wiht the correct token but when i try to plubish my package in github this error ocurrs
An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Please set GITHUB_TOKEN in your environment to access these features
at new GitHub
That´s what i´m trying
my code below
  name: '@electron-forge/publisher-github',
  config: {
    repository: {
      owner: 'xxxxxx',
      name: 'xxxxxx'
    },
    prerelease: true,
    draft: true,
    authToken: process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN,
  }
}

.env file:
GITHUB_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxx


You'll need to require dotenv package for the environment variables to be loaded, although I'm not sure if that would work inside electron-forge config file.
However, you can load the environment variable manually when calling the publish command
export GITHUB_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxx && npm run publish

if you're using windows then use set instead of export
set GITHUB_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxx && npm run publish


edit: this solution is also useful where it uses package.json commands to load env variables from a .env file.
